# Unable to view my apps installed in iPad Air on iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipad

I have iPad Air (first generation) with iOS 8.3 installed. I have iTunes 12.1.2.7 installed on my Windows 8 PC.

I have authorized iTunes to access my iPad but I cannot see any apps in my iTunes when I connect my iPad to PC.

[image: I have apps like Amazon and Tumblr but they do not show up in iTunes]

I have apps like Amazon and Tumblr but they do not show up in iTunes. Can anyone tell me why is this not working?

Comment: Try to scroll the Apps window [not the entire iTunes window, just the Apps pane] Hold your mouse over the pane & scroll the mouse-wheel. I've noticed sometimes it just fails to draw until you do that. Or change to Sort by… something else.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Tried it. Didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: reboot; sync; backup

Comment: scrolling down worked! My mouse couldn't be over the 'Apps' section or 'Home Screens' when I scrolled. It had to be in the margin in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but at least this got the apps synced. So here's what I did.

In the "Home Screens" section open any page. Select and drag any icon moving it to another location or folder. Now in the iTunes you will see buttons of "Apply" and "Revert". Click on "Apply" button and it will start to sync all the apps on your iPad Air to iTunes.

If anyone has a better solution do post it as an answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me this way

Answer (score 2):

You need to scroll down the window a little. Then you can see File sharing. There you can see all the installed apps.

Comment: That lists apps that are capable of File Sharing. That also doesn't provide the ability to remove/install apps which is the primary function of the Apps tab.

Answer (score 1):

I found a convoluted path to get an app to appear.  I went to the iTunes App Store, selected iPad

[image]

In the right column menu I selected Purchased

[image]

I suppose I could have chosen "Download All", but I was interested in only one app, so on that app, I clicked the download from cloud icon in the top right corner of the app icon.  After waiting for the download icon to disappear, when I return to my iPad and the Apps pane, I see the app listed.

Comment: If you're trying to add files to an app, make sure to scroll down to get to the file sharing section that might only appear after doing this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Only apps purchased in the iTunes store of PC or Mac not from the app store of the phone are shown in iTunes apps list. The apps listed there are physically downloaded to PC/Mac drive. Therefore you can install those apps onto your iPhone directly from PC/Mac within iTunes program even without the Internet connection. You also can physically delete downloaded apps at the Apps library of the iTunes.